# Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html) string length less than header EndHTML

Tags: html, vb.net, clipboard

Have some code that looks at HTML on the clipboard. It worked on XP but has the following problem on W7. The HTML clipboard header EndHTML value is greater than the string length of the resulting Clipboard.GetText. Both IE11 and Firefox have the same problem. To test browse to: https://stackexchange.com/

edit select all, and copy. Following code snippet to shows the problem. Maybe something to do with encoding?

```
Dim dto As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
    Dim CBdata As String = ""
    Dim startHTML As String = ""
    Dim endHTML As String = ""
    If dto.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Html) Then
        CBdata = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html)

        Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(CBdata, "StartHTML:(\d+)")
        If m.Success Then startHTML = m.Groups(1).Value
        m = Regex.Match(CBdata, "EndHTML:(\d+)")
        If m.Success Then endHTML = m.Groups(1).Value

        Console.WriteLine("CB data length=" & CBdata.Length.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine("EndHtml=" & endHTML)
        Console.WriteLine("StartHtml=" & startHTML)

        'To get just the html:
        'CBdata.Substring(startHTML, endHTML - startHTML)
        ' but of course throws a subscript exception

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The [StartHTML and EndHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767917.aspx) counters count bytes, not characters. So if you have a text with one UTF8 character that is encoded in two bytes, you'll get the length of 2 instead of 1.

Now, why it worked in XP and now it doesn't in Win 7. It may be a change in .NET 4.5 that I discovered:
[Different behavior of DataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Html) in .NET 4.5](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/different-behavior-of-dataobject-getdata-dataformats-html-in-net-4-5.html)

Comment: Your 4.5 discussion triggered a thought - the XP version is running with a 3.5 target framework and W7 with 4.5. Switched compile options for the W7 version. 4.0 still exhibits the above behavior but 3.5 returns to EndHTML matching string length. This needs further investigation.

Comment: I assume that your W7 has installed .NET 4.5 and 2.0. Even if you compile the program for 4.0, it will run on 4.5 as there is no 4.0 installed on your W7. If you compile for 2.0 (as I did in the mentioned blog post), then it should run on 2.0 because it is installed (as is on most systems). Again,  StartHTML and EndHTML are byte counters so you should never use them for counting the string length directly if the string is not encoded in one-byte encoding.